# Get records from X amount of time and user_id

Tags: mongodb

So I have the following collection structure in Mongo:

```
{
     "comments" : [ 
        {
            "user_id" : 1,
            "full_name" : "Lin-Manuel Miranda",
            "comment" : "Comment 1",
            "posted" : ISODate("2016-09-14T17:23:45.000Z")
        {
            "user_id" : 3,
            "full_name" : "Frank Sinatra",
            "comment" : "Comment 2",
            "posted" : ISODate("2016-09-14T17:23:45.000Z")
        }, 
     ]
}
```

I'm trying to the records where the user_id is 1 and it's posted from X amount of time, so for example:

```
db.getCollection('modulemetas').find({
    $and: [
        {"comments.posted" : { $gt: new Date(ISODate("2016-12-26T17:09:28.000Z")-18*60000)}}, {'comments.user_id' : 1},
        {"comments.user_id" : 1}
    ]
}, {"comments.user_id" : 1})
```

I seem to be getting all the records back, which I can't seem to solve. I don't think `$and` it helping here, so I think that's maybe where I'm going wrong...

Comment: You can find help stackoverflow.com/questions/40937577/…, stackoverflow.com/questions/40941923/…, stackoverflow.com/questions/40680509/… & stackoverflow.com/questions/40932124/…. This all are just different variations of similar problems. Basically you need $filter for your case.

Answer (score 1):

You should use $elemMatch operator.

I played with your data a little bit (in mongo shell),

Initial dataset

```
> db.modulemetas.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5861929820260f49fc374c3e"),
    "comments" : [
        {
            "user_id" : 1,
            "full_name" : "Lin-Manuel Miranda",
            "comment" : "Comment 1",
            "posted" : ISODate("2016-09-14T17:23:45Z")
        },
        {
            "user_id" : 3,
            "full_name" : "Frank Sinatra",
            "comment" : "Comment 2",
            "posted" : ISODate("2016-09-14T17:23:45Z")
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5861936320260f49fc374c3f"),
    "comments" : [
        {
            "user_id" : 1,
            "full_name" : "Lin-Manuel Miranda",
            "comment" : "Comment 1",
            "posted" : ISODate("2016-09-14T17:23:45Z")
        },
        {
            "user_id" : 3,
            "full_name" : "Frank Sinatra",
            "comment" : "Comment 2",
            "posted" : ISODate("2016-12-27T17:23:45Z")
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("586193d320260f49fc374c40"),
    "comments" : [
        {
            "user_id" : 1,
            "full_name" : "Lin-Manuel Miranda",
            "comment" : "Comment 1",
            "posted" : ISODate("2016-12-28T17:23:45Z")
        },
        {
            "user_id" : 3,
            "full_name" : "Frank Sinatra",
            "comment" : "Comment 2",
            "posted" : ISODate("2016-12-27T17:23:45Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

The query you are looking for (you just need to translate it to your driver language):

```
> db.modulemetas.find({comments:{$elemMatch:{posted:{ $gt: new Date(ISODate("2016-12-26T17:09:28.000Z")-18*60000)},user_id : 1}}}, {"comments.user_id" : 1}).pretty()
```

The answer:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("586193d320260f49fc374c40"),
    "comments" : [
        {
            "user_id" : 1
        },
        {
            "user_id" : 3
        }
    ]
}
```

Object with _id "586193d320260f49fc374c40" is the only one with a document that has a comment by user_id 1, and that it is posted after the date defined.

This is mongodb documentation link

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/

Comment: Is it possible to not sure the comments that are not user_id = 1?

Comment: Also, that's greater than the date defined, shouldn't it be within 18 minutes of the date?